# Why Objects cannot be used in switch statement where as enums can be used

Tags: java, enums, switch-statement

Unlike C/C++ java enum is an object. Enum can be used in switch case statements. Where as Objects of class cannot be used. Is there any reason behind this ?

Comment: There is not a general-case O(1) implementation of switch that is even possible for arbitrary Objects, certainly not one you can build at compile time.

Comment: `String` can be used in switch too.

Comment: for general objects, `if - else if - ...` isn't that bad; might even look better than `switch-case`.

Comment: Despite syntactic similarities, Java is neither C nor C++.  Enums can be used in switch statements because Java says they can.  General objects cannot, because Java does not provide for it.  Possible reasons why Java makes that choice include that general objects cannot be expressed as constants, and that general objects do not necessarily have a constant sense of equality.  You can always use `if` blocks instead.

Answer (score 1):

Switch statements are compiled to a jump table. A jump table is a table, which defines for every case statement a line in the code, where the code for the specific case is located. For Example:

```
switch(a) {
    case 0: // Do 0
    case 1: // Do 1
    case 2: // Do 2
}
```

is compiled to:

```
lookupswitch {
    0: 17
    1: 33
    2: 65
}
...
line 17: // Do 0
...
line 33: // Do 1
...
line 65: // Do 2
```

The nice thing about a jump table is that the comparison commands are omitted and you can use them sometimes in an array(here: { 17, 33, 65 }), which omits comparisons.

Because an index in a jump table is a number, you cannot place a function(own objects would need to use the equals function) there. Strings are converted at compile-time to their [hash codes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode--) to compare them in the switch statement. Enums can also easily be indexed by their [ordinal number](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#ordinal--).

Java has defined switch statements like this and for all other usages you can use if/else statements.

Java language reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.11
Java implementation reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-3.html#jvms-3.10
Wikipedia article about jump tables: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_table

Comment: As enums are objects, one has to invoke ordinal() method of the enum class to get ordinal of the enum object. Could you explain in detail how java does that without invoking ordinal() function.